# Overriding DateTimePicker Arrow Key Functionality?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering whether it's possible to override the arrow key functionality that is built into DateTimePickers.  For instance, if you select a DateTimePicker and have the month highlighted, if you press up or down, it changes the month up or down.

I want to get rid of all of this and put my own code in there.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the key stroke event for the date picker.

Drop a dateTimePicker on a form.  Add a KeyDown event.

The code below essentially disables the arrow keys for the date time picker.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Not sure what you want to do, but handle the event however you choose and then mark it as handled.